# Canvas Rotating object about dynamic points

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, html5-canvas

I have a rounded rectangle at a specific x, y, w, h on a canvas. I first do a context.translate to get the object where I want it, then when it comes to rotating it, this is where I'm having issues working out the math needed.

I can do a simple context.rotate(Math.PI/180 * 25) to rotate it 25degs but it rotates from the x,y. I really want to shift the rotating point to like x + (w/2) and y + (w/2).

I'm not sure how to tell the rotate method to rotate it around a different point. I think I have to rotate it like normal but recalculate x,y perhaps based on the rotation maybe?

Comment: I figured it out. The context.translate is actually there the rotate point will be. Just had to adjust the x, y accordingly. Verbalizing my thoughts helped me think it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas **always** rotates about the origin (0,0). The `ctx.translate` command can be thought of as shifting the origin, so you must translate by `(x+w/2, y+h/2)` before you rotate if you wish to rotate about the center of the rectangle.

(and of course, translate back after, or use `save` and `restore`)